# How to do a QML viewer slide itself into the screen

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I plan to add a button on `flow1` that will make `column` slide from right to left very fast so I can change some options and then give it ok so it slides back. It's kinda like when you swipe from left to right on Android and it slides a column for you to make chnges.[image]

As you can see, I placed the `column` right after the `flow1`. The plan is to add an animation that makes both viewers slide left until most of the screen is covered by `column`.

Is this the right way to do it? I don't feel confortable about hiding this off the screen and making them appear.

Is it even possible to animate qt quick positioners?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the [`Drawer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-drawer.html) component (available in Qt 5.7 and greater).

You can control the edge of the window at which the drawer will open from with the [`edge`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-drawer.html#edge-prop) property.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true

    Drawer {
        id: drawer
        width: 0.66 * window.width
        height: window.height

        // Make drawer comes from the right
        edge: Qt.RightEdge


        Column {
            id: column 
            // Your column contents
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly it. But how do I activate it with a button?

Comment: [`Drawer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-drawer.html) inherits from [`Popup`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-popup.html). So you can use the [`open()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-popup.html#open-method) function to make the [`Drawer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-drawer.html) visible.